# mongodb remove documents older than period of time but with no date attribute

Tags: mongodb

we're trying to remove documents older than 3 months in a specific collection.
There's no TTL configured on this collection and no single date/time attribute on those documents.
How can I remove those old documents anyway? is there any script I could run to make it automatically?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did not generate your own `_id` field the [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) contains a timestamp, from the docs:

> The 12-byte ObjectId value consists of: ...

> a 4-byte timestamp value, representing the ObjectId's creation, measured in seconds since the Unix epoch

So if you're using Mongo version 4.0+ you could use [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/), match the documents and overwrite the current collection using [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      shouldKeep: {
        $lt: [
          {
            $subtract: [
              "$$NOW",
              {
                $toDate: "$_id"
              }
            ]
          },
          7776000// 90 days in seconds
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      shouldKeep: true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      shouldKeep: 0
    }
  },
  {
    out: "curr_collection"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c3oFUcYjf3y)

Mind you this is a POC example however this does not deal with many issues, such as timezones. exact month start and ending ( currently it calculates 90 days back ) and more.

Not mentioning that using `$out` on a large collection contains a lot of overhead.
My recommendation is to paginate the results and do this in code.
For `nodejs` for example you can use ObjectId's [getTimestamp](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#getTimestamp) method, like so: (pseudo code)

```
const someDocuments = [...];
for each document:
    const timestamp = document._id.getTimestamp();
    if (timestamp < 3 months ago) delete document.
```

Now in code you can handle timezones, month start dates and scale issues relatively easily.